# Иноглазый или Иноглазной

Tags: приставки, словообразование

Есть слово **иноязычный**. Есть слово **инопланетный**. Есть слово **иностранный** и т.д.

Если мне нужно соединить **"глаз"** и **"ино"**, будет **иноглазый** или **иноглазной**?

Лично мне как-то больше нравится **иноглазый**, но, раз уж я чернилю здесь виртуальные полотна не менее виртуальными чернилами, значит, сомнения имеются у меня.

Comment: Не забывайте, что ещё возможно **иноглазный**.

Answer (score 2):

Если чисто по-философски, то я считаю, что **иноглазый** означало бы *"(человек, зверь, существо) с другими глазами"*. Например,

> иноглазая порода волков

А **иноглазной** - *"для, от, связанно с другими глазами"*.

> требуется иноглазной взгляд

Comment: "пОрода". 
"иноглазной" скорее бы значило - занятый или посторонним образом связанный с другими глазами... ино-глазной врач или ино-глазные очки :> 
Все эти несуществующие конструкции тут звучат ужасно коряво :>

Answer (score 1):

Такого слова нет.

> Если мне нужно соединить "глаз" и "ино",

Зачем? Если это нужно например для worldbuilding — тогда берите, то которое больше нравится. Все равно такого слова нет.